# Fresh React Native Project Fails on IOS build (M1 MacBook)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I created my first react-native project and I started metro just fine. But When I try to run IOS it fails to build. Any suggestions on what I should check?

- latest Xcode installed

```
karar@Karars-MacBook-Air TheGlobalDoctor % npx react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "TheGlobalDoctor.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace TheGlobalDoctor.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme TheGlobalDoctor -destination id=845FA08B-2299-4B05-B9C9-207405392A77")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening TheGlobalDoctor.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace TheGlobalDoctor.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme TheGlobalDoctor -destination id=845FA08B-2299-4B05-B9C9-207405392A77
```

Xcode Failed Build error:

`fatal error: module map file '/Users/karar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheGlobalDoctor-axdadhlgtbbtzcabxyzzteupuwlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found 1 error generated.`

Comment: Hey, could you, please, run your app right from XCode, there will be more informative errors and I will be able to help you, because I had the same problem.

Comment: ``` 
fatal error: module map file '/Users/karar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheGlobalDoctor-axdadhlgtbbtzcabxyzzteupuwlt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
1 error generated. 
```

Comment: Did you try to remove Pods folder from ios and make `pod deintegrate && pod install`?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, same error. Don't expect me to have tried anything, I'm a beginner, barely know anything, thanks

Comment: I've read that re-installing xcode might fix it, but it takes hours for it to reinstall because I'm far from home and wifi speed is pretty low. But let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. You can start XCode using Rosetta to circumvent the problem for now.
To do so open 'Applications' and find XCode. Open it's context menu and select 'Get Info'. In the info view, make sure the "Open using Rosetta" checkbox is checked.

(Thx to Karthik posting the solution in his [blog](https://medium.com/timeless/starting-react-native-project-in-apple-mac-m1-chip-system-28da0c1f2132))

Comment: Didn't fix it for me